# trap kill of a program in bash

Tags: c, bash

what i am trying is, my c exmple has kill() which kills one process. But i want to catch that kill through a bash script so that my execution is done properly.

i have a small example which kills a process.

```
#include <signal.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("before kill");
  kill(0, SIGTERM); // 2265 is a process pid id
  printf("after kill");
}
```

Now i want to trap this kill in bash script. After generating the binary using gcc command, execute the script and nothing happens.

My bash look likes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
term() {
./helloapp
 echo "bash caught TERM"

 }
trap term SIGTERM
```

But its not doing anything. Any suggestion or help is highly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, you run your program *if* a `SIGTERM` is caught, not running it to throw a `SIGTERM`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Are you trying to prevent the process from killing *the shell*, or from killing some other process?

Comment: Your shell script isn't going to be able to *intercept* signals intended for another process. If someone else sends a KILL signal to your C program, your shell script isn't going to be able to do anything about that. (Even more so if the C program is killing *itself* as it appears to be doing here.) However, the shell script can watch the C program and do something after it exits. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: if you are really able to do `kill(0, SIGTERM);` you will have a bad surprise under Linux, the process 0 is not any process :-). More seriously only the process creating a child process will be warn the child process dies

Comment: Dear All, what i am trying is i want to continue my execution for ex: i am trying to print printf("after kill"); after killing a process. i want to use trap as try catch like java though i am not sure this is possible or not.

Comment: @bruno, `kill(0, SIGTERM)` does not mean "send a `SIGTERM` to the process with pid 0."  It means "send a `SIGTERM` to every process in this one's process group".

Comment: Its like @DanielPryden comments

Comment: @JohnBollinger oh yes, 0 is a special case, shame, it would have been funny else

Comment: There's no good reason to have both a custom-written program *and* a custom shell script. Either the program works at sending the signal, and you can reproduce the behavior using only the standard `kill` command (which will send it just as effectively), thus removing `c` from your question entirely, or it *doesn't* work at sending the signal, and you can remove `bash` from your question entirely. Either way, the question should be further narrowed before it's ready to be asked here.

Answer (score 4):

### Shell signal handling

> i have a small example which kills a process.
>
> ```
> #include <signal.h>
>
> int main(void)
> {
>
>   kill(0, SIGTERM);
> }
> ```

Well no, that doesn't just attempt to kill *a* process, it attempts to kill *all* processes in the caller's process group.  That's an important distinction, because having a shell trap that signal protects the shell, but not any other processes in the process group.

> My bash look likes:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
> term() {
> ./helloapp
>  echo "bash caught TERM"
>
>  }
> trap term SIGTERM
> ```
>
> But its not doing anything.

Supposing that `./helloapp` is the process that's going to send the signal, you have completely misunderstood bash's flavor of signal handling.  I suspect that may reflect a misunderstanding of signal handling in general.

You have written the signal handler function as if it provides some kind of signal-handling scope for the commands within, akin to, say, a `try` block in Java.  But signals are not analogous to Java exceptions.  They are asynchronous, outside the normal control flow.  Exceptions can produce transfers of control that would not otherwise be possible, but they still operate within the overall program flow.  Not so signal handling.

The Bash `trap` command does not execute the named shell function.  Rather, it *registers* it as a handler for the specified signal(s).  If that shell process subsequently receives one of the designated signals, then the function will run instead of the default behavior for that signal.  In this case, that can prevent the shell itself from terminating if the process delivers a `SIGTERM` to it.  The appropriate syntax would be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# define signal handler
term_handler() {
  echo "bash caught TERM but refuses to terminate"
}

# register signal handler
trap term SIGTERM

# run process that might send a signal
./helloapp
```

Note, too, that the shell will trap signals from *any* source, not just from commands it runs itself.

But you clarified in comments that what you really want is for the execution of `./helloapp` to continue after it calls `kill()`.  This is not remotely something that you can achieve with a trap in the shell that launches the process.  A trap handles signals delivered to the shell itself, not to any other process.

---

### What you can do instead

So to be clear, the reason your process does not seem to proceed past the `kill()` is that it itself is among the processes to which the `SIGTERM` is delivered, and the default handling for `SIGTERM` is process termination.  When it receives its own signal, it terminates.  You have two options for avoiding that:

1. Have the process avoid signaling itself.  Possible avenues here are

   - have it signal a specific process instead of all processes in its process group

     ```
     kill(a_positive_pid_different_from_mine, SIGTERM);
     ```
   - have it record its original process group number, then put itself in a new process group before killing the original process group.  Assuming that the process is not already a process group leader, that might be:

     ```
     pid_t original_pg = getpgid(0);
     setpgid(0, 0);
     kill(-original_pg, SIGTERM);
     ```
2. Have the process itself register a handler for the signal.  For example, this will make the process ignore the next `SIGTERM` it receives:

   ```
   struct sigaction action = { .sa_handler = SIG_IGN, .sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND };
   sigaction(SIGTERM, &action, NULL);
   ```

Of course, you must always check function return values and handle them properly, at least when you care about whether they completed successfully and / or about what they did.  Such checks are omitted from the above code snippets for clarity.